# Why is this 2 pin 12V mechanical flasher relay on continuously instead of flashing?

Tags: resistors, relay, 12v, coil, indicator

+12V is connected to the B terminal, and one end of a regular bulb is connected to the L terminal, and other end of the bulb is grounded, butthe bulb does not blink at all. It is continuously on.

What is the next step to repair? The capacitor and the resistor are all ok.

[image]

Comment: Such relays are designed for a very specific load. Is your bulb drawing enough current?

Comment: I'm using 12V 5W car parking light.

Comment: A pair of turn signal bulbs will probably be a lot more load than that.

Answer (score 2):

If it's the sort with a heater and a bimetallic strip, then the flash rate depends on the load.  The higher the load, the faster it blinks.

A car usually has 2 x 21W indicator lamps (and maybe a 5W one as well).  Your single 5W lamp is well below that, so it may fail to blink at all.

Comment: alright here is the answer: 21W Bulb makes the relay flashing on and off.